# Using an ESP32 to extend WiFi range?

Tags: wifi, esp32

I currently have an iPhone 14, and noticed i lose my Wi-Fi Connection at about 15 meters from my house. This led me to think, if i walked around with a Wi-Fi module (ESP32) and a large antenna, how much farther could i go and establish a decent Wi-Fi connection. (Using the Esp32 as a repeater that is in my pocket, with a large-ish? antenna) I understand there are a lot of factors at play here, but any general info related to the topic would be beneficial.